# Apache keeps saying: You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!

Tags: macos, osx-server, server.app, apache, webserver

I have configured an SSL web site using the macOS Server app (version 5.3). When I examine the Apache log, I see this message (twice):

```
 [ssl:warn] [pid 4120] AH01916: Init: (mydomain.net:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!
```

I have not made any manual modifications to the Apache config file. I tried deleting the site, then stopping and restarting the web server, and finally re-adding the site from scratch, but the warning continues to show up in the log.

What is wrong and should I care?

Comment: Any solutions found?

Comment: No, I didn’t. Still waiting for a good idea.

Comment: Hmm. Tried removing and re-adding didn't work. Will look into config files see what I could do but it doesn't seem to effect anything.

Comment: Yes, in fact, I decided not to care, but still hoped someone had solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same message. It turned out to be a VirtualHost definition that was missing a ServerName directive. In my case:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAlias hostname-old.domain
  Redirect permanent / https://hostname-new.domain/
</VirtualHost>
```

Which should have been:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName hostname-old.domain
  Redirect permanent / https://hostname-new.domain/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Which configuration file would this be and where (path) would a user find it?

Comment: @not2savvy: This is in the appropriate VHOST configuration file, which, on Linux systems, is usually a soft-link in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`, pointing to an actual file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`. In older implementations, it could be in `/opt/apache/conf/sites-available/*`, or in `/opt/apache/conf/httpd.conf`.

Comment: On macOS with Server app (which this question is about), the path is `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites`.

Answer (score -1):

Check the configuration file of your website for "SSLEngine off". In my case, this setting had been changed by the upgrading process. Changing that line to "SSLEngine on" solved the issue.

Comment: Which configuration file would this be and where (path) would a user find it?